# Issue with the pagination in a custom template

Tags: 7, theming, search

I'm working in Drupal 7.

I have an issue with the search results: I have many records, and only one page with 10 results is generated. If I do a search that have many results (e.g. 50 results) I always see a single page showing 10 results.

If I change the template of a core module, e.g. the Garland theme, the pagination works well; if I set as default the custom template, the pagination doesn't work. In a template what calls the pagination?  Why doesn't the pagination work in the custom template?

The custom template is based on a contributed theme. If I remove the search--results.tpl.php file, I see the pagination, but only two pages for any search. If a search returns 50 results,  I can only see two pages; if the search only has one result, I can only see two pages showing the same result duplicated more than once.

The code contained in the search--results.tpl.php file is the following one.

```
<?php if ($search_results): ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
  <ol class="search-results <?php print $module; ?>-results">
    <?php print $search_results; ?>
  </ol>
  <?php 
       /* $search_conf = variable_get('search_config','');
        $search_limit = $search_conf['results']['limit']; */

  if (stripos($pager,'page=2')) print $pager; ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Your search yielded no results');?></h2>
  <?php print search_help('search#noresults', drupal_help_arg()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The content of the template.php file is the following one.

```
/**
 * Return a themed breadcrumb trail.
 *
 * @param $breadcrumb
 *   An array containing the breadcrumb links.
 * @return a string containing the breadcrumb output.
 */
function MYTHEME_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to
    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' › ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the maintenance page template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$vars) {
  // While markup for normal pages is split into page.tpl.php and html.tpl.php,
  // the markup for the maintenance page is all in the single
  // maintenance-page.tpl.php template. So, to have what's done in
  // MYTHEME_preprocess_html() also happen on the maintenance page, it has to be
  // called here.
  MYTHEME_preprocess_html($vars);
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the html template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  // Toggle fixed or fluid width.
  if (theme_get_setting('MYTHEME_width') == 'fluid') {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'fluid-width';
  }

  $vars['node_type_MYTHEME'] = '';
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $vars['node_type_MYTHEME'] = $node->type; // find your cck field here
  }

  // Add conditional CSS for IE6.
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/fix-ie.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lt IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));

}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the html template.
 */
function MYTHEME_process_html(&$vars) {

  // Hook into color.module
  if (module_exists('color')) {
    _color_html_alter($vars);
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    /*if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type; //
    }*/

    }

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the node template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  if(user_is_logged_in() == 0){
  unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['title']);
  }

  $vars['submitted'] = $vars['date'] . ' — ' . $vars['name'];

  $type = $vars['type'];

  if ($vars['teaser']) { // custom teaser templates
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__teaser';
  }
  if ($vars['teaser'] && $vars['type']) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $type . '__teaser';
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the comment template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  $commentsDate = date('M d, Y',$vars['elements']['#comment']->created);
  $vars['submitted'] =  $vars['author'] . ' — ' . $commentsDate;
  //$vars['submitted'] = $vars['author'];
  $vars['title'] = $vars['elements']['#comment']->subject;
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the block template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  $vars['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'title';
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'clearfix';
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page template.
 */
function MYTHEME_process_page(&$vars) {
  // Hook into color.module
  if (module_exists('color')) {
    _color_page_alter($vars);
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the region template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['region'] == 'header') {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'clearfix';
  }
}

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the region template.
 */
function MYTHEME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#type'] = 'image_button';
  $form['actions']['submit']['#src'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/images/button-search.png';
}


/**
 * Implement themehook_preprocess_user_picture().
 */
/*function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {
$variables['fpublic_path_image_user'] = $variables['account']->picture->uri;
}*/

/**
 * Implement MYTHEME_node_preview for rewrite related message.
 */

function MYTHEME_node_preview($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  $output = '<div class="preview">';

  $preview_trimmed_version = FALSE;

  $elements = node_view(clone $node, 'teaser');
  $trimmed = drupal_render($elements);
  $elements = node_view($node, 'full');
  $full = drupal_render($elements);

  // Do we need to preview trimmed version of post as well as full version?
  if ($trimmed != $full) {
    if(!preg_match('@videos|image@',$node->type)){
    drupal_set_message(t('The trimmed version of your post shows what your post looks like when promoted to the list of pages or when exported for syndication.<span class="no-js"> You can insert the delimiter "&lt;!--break--&gt;" (without the quotes) to fine-tune where your post gets split.</span>'));
    }
    if(!preg_match('@videos|image@',$node->type)){
    $output .= '<h3>' . t('Preview trimmed version') . '</h3>';
    $output .= $trimmed;
    }
    $output .= '<h3>' . t('Preview full version') . '</h3>';
    $output .= $full;
  }
  else {
    $output .= $full;
  }
  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;
}



function MYTHEME_form_element_label($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();

  // If title and required marker are both empty, output no label.
  if ((!isset($element['#title']) || $element['#title'] === '') && empty($element['#required'])) {
    return '';
  }

  // If the element is required, a required marker is appended to the label.
  $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? theme('form_required_marker', array('element' => $element)) : '';

  $title = filter_xss_admin($element['#title']);

  $attributes = array();
  // Style the label as class option to display inline with the element.
  if ($element['#title_display'] == 'after') {
    $attributes['class'] = 'option';
  }
  // Show label only to screen readers to avoid disruption in visual flows.
  elseif ($element['#title_display'] == 'invisible') {
    $attributes['class'] = 'element-invisible';
  }

  if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
    $attributes['for'] = $element['#id'];
  }

    if($element['#parents'][0] == 'field_image' && $element['#title'] == 'Title'){
    return ' <label' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $t('Image Caption !required', array('!title' => $title, '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }   else {
    // The leading whitespace helps visually separate fields from inline labels.
    return ' <label' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $t('!title !required', array('!title' => $title, '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the code that appears in the next page:  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7 and I changed the THEME_pager() by MYTHEME_pager() and didn't work the code.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What theme are you using? If it is custom, is it based on a contributed theme? Do you have search-results.tpl.php in your theme? You do not need this or the THEMENAME_pager() function in your theme, but if you do have them, they may be incorrectly overriding the default behavior and would give a clue as to a possible cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the search--result.tpl.php in my theme and now shows only two pages with results and no more.  If I have 200 results only show two pages with 10 results each one.

Comment: @cabita Do you have any other content on the page that also has a pager? For example a list of content in a block generated by a View?

Comment: Hi Clive.  Thanks for your help.  In a block generated by a View the pagination is shown.  The pager fails in the coments and the search.

Answer (score 4):

In your search-results.tpl.php file you've got this line near the bottom:

```
if (stripos($pager,'page=2')) print $pager; ?>
```

That line is definitely not part of the [standard search-results.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7) and would definitely cause strange issues when outputting the pager.

Try changing that line to simply:

```
print $pager;
```

That should solve the problem. :)

Comment: I want to comment that I have in the theme this file in the folder template_search. When I delete this file the results are always two pages for any search, and if I keep the file in the folder themplate_search, it only shows 10 results without pagination.

Comment: I did the change and the issues with the search continue.  Only show two pages of results.  I must to modify directly the search--results.tpl.php in mysite/modules/search/theme?

Comment: I put this code in the search-results.tpl.php :  http://pastebin.com/r4BaRtNX and flush the cache and the results of the searchs continue showing two pages of results and no more.

Comment: That's very strange. It sounds like a contributed or custom module that you've got installed is causing the problem...do you have any contributed search modules installed? If so do you know which one(s)?

Comment: The only module is search configuration, and I have uninstalled and tested and the issue continue.

Comment: It just gets stranger :) It sounds like a module must be interfering, but at the same time it doesn't make sense that the pager works with any theme except your custom one. That surely must mean it's a problem with the theme. Is it a custom theme you've created yourself or one you've purchased/inherited?

Comment: It's a custom theme created for my designer.

Comment: If you want to zip up a copy of the theme and email it to me I'd be happy to enable it in a site and see if I can reproduce the problem...it will at least help you to narrow down where the issue is

Comment: Hi Clive.  Thanks for your help.  I'll give the points for your help.  In this moment is not possible to send the full theme.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I couldn't help any more

Comment: with $page array (Devel module) **review the list of regions in $page array (in your page of results)**, then review Blocks **within these regions** that have Views with pager. If you have, then change the ID of pager of respective view Block (remember that you can use the theme_pager() function in your template.php of your theme)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. edit the the view for block with pagination (you said in a comment that you have such a block);
2. go to the "pager" section and click on "paged, x items" (x is the number of items you display)
3. change "pager ID" to a different number
4. save the view

I think that your block is overriding the main pager. By changing that ID you tell Drupal that it should use 2 different pagers on the same page.

Comment: That was all in my original answer (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/25700/revisions), it didn't help unfortunately :)